# OpenStruct.new stores attribute but doesn't retrieve it

Tags: ruby, null, openstruct

After creating a new Ruby OpenStruct object, I am able to store attributes but not to retrieve them (I get a blank line and it returns `nil` instead):

```
obj = OpenStruct.new # => #<OpenStruct>
obj.x = 10
obj.y = 20
obj                  # => #<OpenStruct x=10, y=20>
obj.x                # => 10
obj.y                #  
                     # => nil
```

If I try to store other properties with different names, everything works as expected. This problem seems to happen only when I store a property named `y`. I'm using the following version:

`ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [i686-linux]`

Does anybody have an idea of what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something somewhere is pulling in [`Psych`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html) for YAML stuff. Psych [patches `Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Kernel.html) to add a `psych_y` method which is aliased to `y`. So, everything has a `y` method defined:

```
> o = OpenStruct.new
> o.method(:y)
 => #<Method: OpenStruct(Kernel)#psych_y>
```

AFAIK, OpenStruct uses [`method_missing`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) and an internal Hash to produce accessor and mutator methods; but, there's already a `y` from that "friendly" patch to Kernel so OpenStruct's magic doesn't get to handle the `y` method because Psych's magic is in the way. The mutator, `y=`, is fine though so you can safely `o.y = 11` and see your `11` inside `o`.

You could remove the `y` like this:

```
> o = OpenStruct.new
> o.class_eval('undef_method :y')
> o.y = 11
> o.y
 => 11
```

You could probably remove the method from `Kernel` and hope that nothing depends on that silly `y` alias:

```
> Kernel.send(:undef_method, :y)
> o = OpenStruct.new
> o.y = 11
> o.y
 => 11
```

Or you could just remove it from `OpenStruct`:

```
> OpenStruct.send(:undef_method, :y)
> o = OpenStruct.new
> o.y = 11
> o.y
 => 11
```

This sort of thing is why a lot of people don't like monkey patching, especially monkey patching something as fundamental as `Kernel`.